# Me podéis asesorar con un redireccionamiento

Tags: .htaccess

Tengo una cadena de url que contienen esto después del dominio:

```
/?i=B0786X76
```

He probado esto, pero no me funciona:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(.+)i=(.+)$ https://prodecona.com/$1
```

y

```
RewriteRule (.+)i=(.+)$ https://prodecona.com [R=301,L]
```

Gracias y cuidaros mucho

Comment: por favor dale a [edit] explicando qué quieres que ocurre y qué está ocurriendo. "Problema" es algo demasiado genérico

Comment: es posible que te falte el segundo grupo con el id y que quieras el RewriteRule?
```RewriteRule ^/(.+)i=(.+)$ https://prodecona.com/$1/$2 [R=301,NC,L]```

Comment: No No funciona así

Answer (score 0):

Hola después de muchas pruebas he conseguido que me redireccione a una pagina 404. No es lo que quería pero de momento me sirve. Si tenéis una sugerencia mejor la probare.
Este es el código que he utilizado:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*[&?]option=)?i=(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://prodecona.com/404.php? [R=301,L]
```

Si quito el interrogante después de 404.php me sale con la cadena que es en realidad la que quiero eliminar.
Saludos